# Posting data on server using asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms

I have name and email id fields and want to post data to server to another website (if fields are valid) using form tags but i already have one form tag with runat="server", using second form tag causes second form to not show on page. I have JavaScript code to post data to server on form post. I saw something using action on button click, but how do i post data on button click

P.S I don't want to use iFrame, popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send POST data on a form submit, try to use a submit button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="POST_DATA" name="POST_PARAMETER_NAME">
```

Replace `POST_DATA` with your data you want to submit and replace `POST_PARAMETER_NAME` with the parameter name you want to access the data on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a form on the page that uses asp.net web forms to communicate with the server then you would probably need to make an ajax request if you want to post back different data. This is quite easy these days using jQuery. The link bellow shows you how you may do this and how to create a web forms page that would accept your post. This way your current form and page would not need to change which is what it sounds like you are after.

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: thanks for your help but while posting data i am getting an error:

Comment: Thanks, i did using form tag with controls without post buttons as it may cause issues.